# How to animate plane to sound falloff in animation nodes 2.1 (Blender 2.8)?

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes, audio

For Blender 2.8, i tried to recreate the sound falloff on a plane from the Animation nodes 2.0 Documentation:

[image]

So far i came up with this, but it does not work, i can not figure out why:
[image]

Can someone give a brief explanation of how to work with the new Sound Spectrum node in the latest animation node version? The Grid mesh node has also changed. Is this causing the error?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Connect "Frame" to Time Info node in Sound Falloff node so that it has frame information

Comment: Please include more detail to improve this answer.

Answer (score -2):

hey man first thanks for the post this is what I ended up with. Its working its been tested. [image]